# How to split subtables across multi pages?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering


\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\centering
table materials
\caption{sub table 1 }
\end{subtable}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\centering
table materials
\caption{sub table 2 }
\end{subtable}


\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\centering
table materials
\caption{sub table 3 }
\end{subtable}

\caption{Overall caption}
\end{table}
```

It always takes one whole page for a table with its subtables. So the previous page has a lot empty. So does the later page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `subtable`s are necessarily wrapped in a `table` which can not break across pages. I don't know if `subtables` work inside of a `longtable`, but you might explore it. Otherwise consider a restructure of your code

Comment: @cmhughes, Hello. Thank you for your comment. As you said, I have t o use other structure. So could you recommend one to me ?

Comment: What works for tables works for figures as well, and vice versa. I suggest to close this as duplicate. No need to write up an extra answer, imho.